# I need with parsing an array from google script to HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a date picker that I'd like to use to choose an event and then show details from a spread sheet.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>

  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {

            var stuff= updDate(date);

        },
        selectWeek: true,
        inline: true,
        startDate: '01/01/2000',
        firstDay: 1,
    });
  });
  </script>

    <script>
      function updDate(date){

      google.script.run.updDate(date);

      }


</script>
</head>


<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onchange="updDate()"></p>
 Hello, world!
<input type="button" value="Close"
  onclick="google.script.host.close()" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Google Script:

```
function updDate(date){

  var searchString = date;
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("*************");
 var row = new Array();





  var k;


  for (var i in data) {
    //Logger.log("length is:  "+data[i].length)
    //var p = data[i].length
    for (var j in data[i]) {
      //Logger.log("We are at i:  "+i) //Row
      //Logger.log("We are at j:  "+j) //Col
      if (i !=0){
        if(data[i][j] != ""){
          if(j == 4){
            //Logger.log("date from picker:  " + date);
            //Logger.log("date from Data:  " + data[i][j]);
            var ssDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][j], "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
            //Logger.log("date post Convert:  " +ssDate);
            if(date == ssDate){


              k= i
              var p = data[i].length
              Logger.log("P is:  " +p);

            }
          }

        }
        }
      }
    }
  Logger.log("K is:  "+k)

  var q = 1
  while (q <= p){

    row[q] = data[k][q];


    q++
  }

  Logger.log("Row:  " +row);
  return row;
  }
```

Eventually I'd like to get the data read into a table but I've been hitting a wall when it comes to successfully getting the data read into a variable in the HTML.

Right now I get this error:

> Uncaught ScriptError: The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type.

Any help in returning the array "row"(in the google script) to the variable "stuff"(in the HTML) successfully or any pointers about how to better execute this task would be greatly appreciated.

Loren

Edit code:

```
   function updDate(date){


      var stuff = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myReturnFunction).updDate(date);
      Console.log(stuff)

      }
      function myReturnFunction(){
         window.myReturnFunction = function(whatGotReturned) {console.log(whatGotReturned);};

         }
```

Comment: Are you running it as a webapp? If so, don't you need a doGet function?

Comment: I'm running it as part of a spreadsheet.

Comment: You should put an `.onSuccess(functionHere)` line in your code.  `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myReturnFunction).updDate(date);  Then create the myReturnFunction.  window.myReturnFunction = function(whatGotReturned) {console.log(whatGotReturned);};

Comment: @SandyGood is the Edit above what you intended for my code.  Or should the line window.myReturnFunction be separate from myReturnFuntion?

Comment: When Apps Script serves the HTML, everything gets changed and sanitized with Caja.  Anywhere you write a function with the syntax `function myFunctionName() { code here;};` Caja changes it to `window.myFunctionName = function() {code here;};`  So, I just write it that way to begin with.  You don't need both, it's either one or the other.

Comment: If I have a function in google code foo that is returning bar, shouldn't the html function look like this:  var whatsreturnedtoHTML=google.script.run.foo(); regardless of if you have a success handler or not?

Answer (score 0):

Sandy Good had it right in the comments above:

```
 function updDate(date){


      var junk = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myReturnFunction).updDate(date);


      }
      function myReturnFunction(whatGotReturned){

        console.log(whatGotReturned);

         }
```